# Determining copy/write progress with FileSystemWatcher in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, filesystemwatcher

**Context:** A team of operators work with large batch files up to 10GB in size in a third party application. Each file contains thousands of images and after processing every 50 images, they hit the save button. The work place has unreliable power and if the power goes out during a save, the entire file becomes corrupt. To overcome this, I am writing a small utility using the FileSystemWatcher to detect saves and create a backup so that it may be restored without the need to reprocess the entire batch.

**Problem**: The FileSystemWatcher does a very good job of reporting events but there is a problem I can't pinpoint. Since the monitored files are large in size, the save process takes a few seconds. I want to to be notified once the save operation is complete. I suspect that every time the file buffer is flushed to disk, it triggers an unwanted event. The file remains locked for writing whether or not the a save is in progress so I cannot tell that way.

Creating a backup of the file DURING a save operation defeats the purpose since it corrupts the backed file.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to use the FileSystemWatcher to be notified after the save operation is complete?
- If not, how else could I reliably check to see if the file is still being written to?

**Alternatives:** Any alternative suggestions would be welcome as well.

Comment: Take a look at this article perhaps there is a way to do what you are wanting to do by using Threading.. but based on what you are wanting to do you can't do it with just a FileSystemWatcher.. 
http://csharp-codesamples.com/2009/02/file-system-watcher-and-large-file-volumes/

Comment: Thanks. You should have posted this as an answer. A threaded queue with a conditional cancellation token seems to be the way. The token could be used to cancel copy operations if an update is detected during copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no direct way to do exactly what you're trying to do. The file system itself doesn't know when a save operation is completed. In logical terms, you may think of it as a series of saves simply because the user clicks the Save button multiple times, but that isn't how the file system sees it. As long as the application has the file locked for writing, as far as the file system is concerned it is still in the process of being saved.

If you think about it, it makes sense. If the application holds onto write access to the file, how would the file system know when the file is in a "corrupt" state and when it's not? Only the application writing the file knows that.

If you have access to the application writing the file, you might be able to solve this problem. Failing that, you might be able to get something with the last modified date, creating a backup only if the file isn't modified for a certain period of time, but that is bound to be buggy and unreliable.

Comment: Sad. Your last paragraph seems to be the only viable option. Short of hooking into the third-party app which is equally unreliable. The file system SHOULD support some kind of atomicity.

Comment: Technically it does - the file locks are the atomicity. When you lock a file, you're telling the file system that it is in flux and not complete. When you unlock it, that's when the file system knows it is in a "correct" state. This is the fault of the third-party application which keeps the handle locked in-between saves.

Comment: I agree although there are situations which justify an unconditional lock. What I meant though, was that the file system itself should promote atomic-friendly APIs to encourage responsible development rather than the 'i-do-as-i-please-since-it's-proprietary' approach which still seems popular. I say that because in most situations, the cause is a result of developer decisions rather than proprietor.

Comment: I agree with you 100% on that. I think I'm one of the few Windows developers who is really looking forward to the new development models  and APIs under WinRT.